# Claws-Mail Spell Checker Not Finding hunspell-en_CA

Tags: email, spell-checking, dictionary, hunspell

I'm running the latest Claws-Mail (v3.17.6) on Arch Linux and downloaded the latest hunspell-en_CA package (v2019.10.06). When I go to 'Configuration > Preferences > Spell Checking' the 'Default Dictionary' drop down has nothing in it.

I found the hunspell dictionary files are located in '/usr/share/hunspell/'. Is Claws-Mail looking in a different directory? Can I maybe link to these files?

Does anyone know how to get this working in Claw-Mail?

EDIT:
Here's the error message that I get when I compose or reply/forward to an email.

`Spell checker could not be started. Couldn't initialize None dictionary: (null) Couldn't initialize None speller.`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you installed `enchant` package? https://www.claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/Installation_and_Configuration#Can_I_use_a_spell_checker_with_Claws_Mail.3F

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have the enchant package installed. I navigated to claws-mail link that you sent and it says to run .configure. This I didn't do. Are they talking about '/usr/share/libtool/configure'

Comment: Which OS (Linux distribution) do you use?  Mist distribution should auto-configure installed software package.

Comment: Arch Linux (5.7.11-arch1-1).

Comment: I use FreeBSD, so I have to install these packages `enchant` + lang packs, like `en-hunspell`,  `pl-hunspell`. After that, Claws-mail allows me to pick a lang in `Configuration` > `Preferences` > `Compose, Spell Checking` > `Dictionary`. Previously it was empty/grayed, now works correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did everything that I could think of to get the new `hunspell-en_CA` package working with Claws-Mail. Nothing worked, but I did find that if you ditch the `hunspell-en_CA` package and load the `aspell-en` package everything will magically start to work. No need to run ./configure or anything... Just restart the application.

If need be, uncheck the checkbox `Enable Spell Checker` under `Configuration > Preferences > Spell Checking` click OK and go back in and re-check the box once again. The drop down should now show a list of english options.